# Auto-update Complexity Zoo references?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Since the complexity zoo is such a common resource on this site, but it moves around its URL every few years it seems, it'd be nice to have an automated or semi-automated way to update references to the zoo without relying on people to notice them and update them. In questions and answers, updating a zoo reference currently requires updating the question/answer, which isn't desirable (too many edits causes things to automatically become CW, as I recall). In comments, they can't even be updated after a certain short time has elapsed, so someone actually has to post a new comment, which leads to an (unnecessary) proliferation of comments.

I don't know that I have a question here, more looking for thoughts & suggestions on if other people agree it's a good idea, and how to make it happen.

Comment: The Community Wiki issue has been fixed actually: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/271610

Comment: One low-tech approach would be to just edit the links when they appear in a post you're reading

Comment: Ah, with the CW issue fixed I don't see any issue w/ updating links as you see them, for questions and answers. But in comments you basically just have to post a new comment, which muddies things up (I saw a post recently with a bunch of comments, 3 of which were just updating zoo links from other comments). It'd be nice if on the backend mods could do an automated search to update them all in one go (esp. if/when the zoo changes its url again).

Comment: I think updating many at once can only be done by SO developers, although moderators could perhaps ask developers

Comment: You can flag a comment that has a wrong link for moderator attention and then we can edit it for you.

Comment: The devs indeed have a URL rewriting tool. It was e.g. recently used to fix arXiv mirror links on Mathoverflow. Do we know how many links are affected?

Comment: Here is my posts on [math.meta.se] which lists examples of some cases where the tool for mass-replacement of URLs was used: [Domains with dead links](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34712). The instance mentioned by @EmilJeřábek was requested in this post: [Updated: Is it time to replace links to the UCDavis arXiv frontend?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5124)

Comment: As a side note, I think that ([meta-tag:hyperlinks]) might a suitable tag here. (Some meta sites have even a separate tag for broken/dead links, but I do not see such tag here.)

Comment: As a side note, I'll mention this old post of mine (with basically no response): [Would it be possible to use something like Wikipedia's templates here?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3277)